# Is image type not supported in code first configuration any longer?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Using EF4.3 Code First with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express (version 10.0.5500).

I am trying to set the `ColumnType` property in my model to instruct the database to use the `image` datatype for a column instead of the default `varbinary(max)`. I have tried using both data annotations `[Column(TypeName="image")]` and the Fluent API: `.HasColumnType("image")`.

Neither seems to work (although no exceptions generated), the type of the database column remains `varbinary(max)` after re-creation.

All other configuration seems to work fine.

Is this datatype no longer supported in Code First?  It seems to be still supported in SQL Server 2008 R2 Express if I look at the database in SSMS.

Thanks

Comment: The `IMAGE` datatype **is** deprecated since SQL Server **2005** - why do you insist on using it (instead of its replacement - `varbinary(max)`) ?

Comment: No insistence, was just following an example.  Didn't realize it was deprecated, thanks.